# How to tell if laptop supports SSD

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, ssd, lenovo-laptop

So I was considering buying a **Lenovo Z710 laptop - 59421370** which you can see the specs [here](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/lenovo/z-series/z710/?sb=:000001C9:00013EDA:)

I noticed that it has an SSHD drive which I don't like. I jumped to the online chat and asked an assistance to see if there is an option to exchange SSHD with an SSD drive but he said this laptop does not support SSD and does not have an mSATA port. Which is strange because my 4-year old laptop supports 2½" SSD's.

How can I tell if it supports SSD or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your laptop [has a regular SATA](http://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/ideapad_z710_hmm.pdf)<sup>*</sup> drive. That means you can use a normal SATA based SSD.

The link you mention in your post probably points to a different kind of micro SSD which requires a special slot on the motherboard (that is the mSATA port you mentioned). and which is often used as a sort of extra HDD cache.  However the link does not work for me (I get the main page but no buttons work).

---

<sup>*</sup>: See page 27 in the link.

Comment: @norbertpy yes in the general case, some laptops are more challenging than others when it comes to components.  Most will simply have a hdd bay or cover that allows for easy access.  Some you will need to partially disassemble the laptop to get at the drive.